# Using leftCorner/rightCorner in TabViewStyle in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am using Qt 5.1 – QML desktop components. For TabView, I want to have my tabs aligned right but the tabbar should start after a button at top-right corner. I am able to align tabs right using:

```
 tabsAlignment: Qt.AlignRight
```

However, I am not able to place a button at right corner. Tried this but didn’t work.:

```
 padding.right: 60
```

I saw that in TabViewStyle, we have rightCorner which is set to null. I tried to put in it rectangle or my own custiom button but it didn’t appear:

```
rightCorner:
        Rectangle{
        width: 60
        height: 60
        color: "red"
    }
```

Please help on using rightCorner or solving this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the source code of QtQuick controls, it seems like the corners need to have an `implicitWidth` as well as an `implicitHeight`. It does not work with components that only have `width` and `height`.

```
TabView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    style: TabViewStyle {
        rightCorner: Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                implicitWidth: 20
                implicitHeight: 20
        }
    }
    Tab { title: "Tabby" }
    Tab { title: "Tabby" }
    Tab { title: "Tabby" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. All I noticed is that not all components work. A Text{} or an Item{} component work fine, but as you mentioned, a Rectangle{} component can't be added outright, you'd have to wrap it in an Item, like so:

```
rightCorner: Item{
    Rectangle{
        width: 60
        height: 60
        color: "red"
    }
}
```